# How to choose items from locations FIFO with minimum visits (most efficiently)

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, entity-framework, neural-network

I have a list of items in my database with inventory at locations: I'm using Entity Framework and C#.

```
public class Item {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }

}
public class Inventory {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
}
public class Location {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So for example, say I need:

- 50 Cola bottles
- 100 Pepsi bottles

And I have (age, name - qty, location)

- 2, Cola  - 25, Loc1
- 2, Pepsi - 100, Loc1
- 2, Cola - 25, Loc2
- 1, Cola - 50, Loc3

I need to be able to sort this list by the order in which it is most efficient to pick it, there are 2 rules for the process:

1. Need to pick the oldest items first (Lowest age numbers go first)
2. Need to visit the least amount locations as possible

Under certain scenarios there will be a conflict where there is a way to increase efficiency by visiting a single location for multiple items, but it will leave behind an older product, which is OK but it will have to adhere to some sort of threshold determined by how many location visits we've saved or something.

Either way, I don't know where to start in coding this up.

How can this be done?

Comment: How many items and locations are there?  If we forget about the age information and the numbers of items, this is equivalent to the Set Cover problem, which is already NP-hard; adding those extra requirements just makes it even harder.  So don't expect an efficient algorithm if there are lots of items or locations.

Comment: This algorithm will only need to be applied to 30 complete inventory records at most.

Comment: I would probably just try enumerating all possible sets of locations in increasing order of number of locations: i.e. all single locations, then all pairs of locations, etc.  At each point when adding a location to a set, I would ignore it if it contained no items that I still need.  I would also keep track of the newest item taken from a location in the current partial solution (location set) so far: you can use this to rank solutions of the same size (the older the newest item is, the better a solution it is).

Comment: There are many pairs of same-size solutions that that ordering won't distinguish between -- specifically, whenever the newest item in two solutions is the same (or just has the same age), it won't distinguish them.  So it might be better to compute weighted sums of the ages instead -- weighting each age by the number of items of that age.  This is equivalent to minimising the *average* item age (since you could get that by dividing through by the total number of items, which is fixed).

Comment: Final thought: The original ordering scheme is better in one respect: it allows (maybe quite a lot of) pruning of larger solutions.  Specifically, suppose you have a solution that uses 3 locations and which has a newest item that is 10 days old.  As soon as you start generating solutions with 4 or more locations, you can immediately ignore any location with needed items that are 10 days old or less -- since you already have a solution that uses fewer locations and has the same or better newest age :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thank you so much, there's a lot to think about and look into there. Do you have any implementation ideas? Am I looking at a neural net here? a bunch of for loops? Do you know of a resource I could look at and learn from that is similar to my problem?

Comment: You're welcome :)  All you need is a way to generate all subsets, incrementally (i.e. so that we don't waste time considering subsets containing locations that we decided early on we don't need).  There's an easy recursion for this; searching for "generate all subsets" on here or Google should find it.  To generate them in increasing size order, you would need an outermost loop from 1 up to |locations|, and your recursive function would take an extra parameter recording the number of locations left to add, which you would initially set to that loop counter, and decrease on each recursive call.

Comment: BTW when I say "easy recursion", it's easy *if you already understand recursion* -- but understanding recursion can take a while, so don't feel bad if it doesn't click right away! ;)

Comment: I understand recursion, this is probably one of the hardest problems I've faced as a programmer though. You've pretty much answered my question so thank you again. If you feel like putting this info into an answer I'll give you the tick for it :)

Comment: I've added an answer, which is mostly the same but a bit reorganised.  Note the "NOTE:" part -- I realised later that we need to not "commit too early" to picking up items!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we forget about the age information and the numbers of items, this is equivalent to the Set Cover problem, which is already NP-hard; adding those extra requirements just makes it even harder.

### Brute force enumeration

I would probably just try enumerating all possible sets of locations in increasing order of number of locations: i.e. all single locations, then all pairs of locations, etc.  At each point when adding a location to a set, I would ignore it if it contained no items that I still need.

All you need is a way to generate all subsets, incrementally (i.e. so that we don't waste time considering subsets containing locations that we decided early on we don't need), keeping track of the number of items of each type you still need as you generate each one*.  There's an easy recursion for this; searching for "generate all subsets" on here or Google should find it.  To generate them in increasing size order, you would need an outermost loop from 1 up to |locations|, and your recursive function would take an extra parameter recording the number of locations left to add, which you would initially set to that loop counter, and decrease on each recursive call.

* **NOTE:** It's actually not quite as simple as the above suggests, because if we add a new location to our current partial solution that contains older items, we want to be able to use those items instead of ones we picked out earlier.  So we need to track more than just the number of items of each type that we still need to choose: we also need to track, for each item type, the number of items of that type *of each age* that we have already chosen.  I think the easiest way would be to not commit to choosing items at all until we have finished building the partial solution; instead, we track the "pool" of items and ages of all locations that we visit, and only choose among them at the end.  Specifically, as we construct a partial solution, for each desired item type we keep a list sorted in decreasing age order (or better yet a heap/priority queue -- this will be faster to update) that contains an (age, available count) pair for every location that we have visited and which stocks that item.  Then when we have finished constructing the partial solution, we can just read pairs from the front of this list (or pop the heap) until we have extracted enough items; these will be the oldest items that we could get from the set of locations that we visited.

### How to compare solutions

Before we can find the "best" solution, we need to define what "best" means, which means we need a way of comparing two solutions to see which one is better -- in other words, we want an *order* on the set of valid solutions.  For this problem, we only have vague, competing requirements that we should prefer solutions that visit few locations, as well as solutions that use old items.  This isn't enough to completely specify an order, so a compromise is to look for a small set of solutions.  I think it would be useful to report the "best" solution for each size (number of locations) -- if there are at most 30 inventory records then there will be at most 30 such solutions, which should be a small enough list for a human to work with.

Even if we only consider solutions of a particular size, we still don't have enough information in the problem specification to select a particular order -- is a 2-location solution that uses 25-day-old Cola items and 50-day-old Pepsi items better or worse than a 2-location solution that uses 50-day-old Cola items and 25-day-old Pepsi items?  Nevertheless we can still look for orders that make the right choice when it's "obvious", like when the oldest item in one solution is newer than the newest item in the other.  Both of the following orders have this property.

**Order by newest item:** You can keep track of the newest item taken from a location in the current partial solution (location set) so far.  The older the newest item is, the better a solution it is.

**Order by average item age:** There are many pairs of same-size solutions that the previous ordering won't distinguish between -- specifically, whenever the newest item in two solutions is the same (or just has the same age), it won't distinguish them.  So it might be better to compute weighted sums of the ages instead -- weighting each age by the number of items of that age.  This is equivalent to minimising the average item age (since you could get that by dividing through by the total number of items, which is fixed).

The newest-item ordering scheme is better than the average-age scheme in one respect: it allows (maybe quite a lot of) pruning of larger solutions. For example, suppose you have a solution that uses 3 locations and which has a newest item that is 10 days old.  As soon as you start generating solutions with 4 or more locations, you can immediately ignore any location *with needed items* that are 10 days old or less -- since you already have a solution that uses fewer locations and has the same or better newest age :)

Comment: You really go the extra mile, i can't thank you enough :) I'll be a happy man if my code is a tenth as elegant and in depth as this answer.